# makefile issues on '%'

Tags: makefile

I wrote a simple makefile, which would copy all .txt files from /src to /dest directory. But it does not work.

I guess the problem is around '%', but I cannot find it. Can you help me?

The Makefile:

```
all:dest/%.txt

dest/%.txt: src/%.txt
    @[ -d dest ] || mkdir dest
    cp $< $@
```

Error info:
make: *** No rule to make target `dest/%.txt', needed by`all'.  Stop.

===============================

Thanks for all answers! Now I understand what this makefile does. If I modify the first line to "all:dest/a.txt", meanwhile there is a.txt in src/ directory. It will only copy src/a.txt to dest/a.txt, instead of copying all files in src/.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wildcards for that.

```
all:
     cp src/*.txt dest/
```

Comment: This copies every file every time not just changed source files.

Comment: Is just an example, not "copy/paste" use

Comment: That makes this *less* useful of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%` notation with generic recipes, such as a rule for compiling C files into object files.

You can't use it in a target like you're trying to do.

Consider the case where there are no `.txt` files in the `dest` directory.  There's nothing to tell `make` which files it should copy into the directory.

I tend to work with old-school `make`, and I don't use wildcards in a `makefile`.  So, I'd list the files I want in the directory and write a conditional copy rule.

Comment: Don't you mean *prerequisite* instead of *target*? Every pattern rule *must* have a `%` in its target. The problem is with the `%` in the first rule, which isn't being interpreted as a pattern rule because the target *lacks* a `%`.

Comment: @reinierpost: I was referring to `all`, the target, though the notation is being used as a dependency or prerequisite of the target.  It's a little open to debate.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It seems ok to me

Comment: I agree that prerequisite would likely be the most accurate term here but I don't think the use of target is problematic enough to be concerned about.